# Can I turn Google Apps Script libraries on an off programmatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have a pile of spreadsheet functions that I want to distribute. I'd actually like to charge for them, keeping them functional and accessible for as long as the in-app-subscription is current and then making them unavailable until the subscription is renewed.

So while I figure out how to set up a subscription mechanism for Google Apps Script (has this already been worked out somewhere?), how do you keep people from using your collection?

I had thought of something like

```
function WHATEVER() {
    if (!Subscribed()) {
        return new Error("Subscription not current");
    }
    // ... rest of function
}
```

That's fine I suppose, but is there a better way?

Comment: There is a GitHub repository for Apps Script subscriptions at [Andrew Roberts - Subs](https://github.com/andrewroberts/Subs)

Comment: Apps Script custom functions are assumed deterministic based on arguments alone. So there is no specification that says your custom functions will stop working once the user subscription expires (or that they will start once the user re-ups).

Comment: The [tag:in-app-subscription] tag about a Google Play feature. It doesn't apply to Google Apps Script question like this.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing persistent storage every time a function runs in order to test for whether the user is still subscribed or not, increases processing time.  So, your `Subscribed()` function should cache the current paid status in order to avoid reading Properties Service, (Or wherever you've stored the expiration date) every time a function runs.

But even using cache could be a burden.  I'm not sure how much of a burden it would be, you'll need to test it or get user feedback.

You could also check the current paid status when a sidebar or dialog opens, or when the spreadsheet opens if you wanted to avoid running a test every time a function runs.  But then there's the problem of how do you stop the function from running.

Because every function name is different, you'd need to add your `if` statement to every function, but I don't think there is any alternative to having a test in every function.

You didn't show your `Subscribed()` function, so I'll provide a suggestion.

```
function Subscribed_() {
  var cache,usrProps,expireDate,todaysDate;
  cache = CacheService.getUserCache();

  todaysDate = new Date();
  todaysDate = todaysDate.getTime();//Today's date in milliseconds

  expireDate = cache.get('expDate');//Get the expiration date

  if (expireDate === null) {//No value stored in cache
    //Now look up persistent value
    usrProps = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
    expireDate = usrProps.get('expDate');//Get the expiration date
  }

  if (!expireDate) {
    return false;
  }

  expireDate = Number(expireDate);//Store the expiration date in milliseconds

  if (todaysDate < expireDate) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

}
```